# Is this the right datatype list to use, and how do I declare a size of empty 0s?

Tags: list, scala

I am trying to create a list/array where I can update the elements at specific indices freely. I assume I will need a mutable list for this. I need all elements defaulted to 0. I tried this:

```
val arr = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Int].fill(100)(0);
```

To make an array of size 100 with all 0's, but it doesn't like this. How to correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the type, as you want to call the `fill` method on the companion object:

```
var arr = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList.fill(100)(0)
```

The reason why the two differ is that with `MutableList.fill` you are accessing the `companion object` of the class `MutableList` while with `MutableList[Int]` you are implicitly calling the class constructor: `MutableList[Int]()` and the new instance does not have a `fill` method.

Comment: huh! how about that. Why doesn't it like having Int specified? (I can accept in 8)